# Suddenly unable to play videos and audios on FlowPlayer

Tags: audio, flowplayer

Couple of day again flow player stop playing audio and video files. This is my code

```
<div id="player" style="display:block;width:728px;height:330px;"></div>
<script>
    $f("player", "https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf", {
      clip: {
        url: 'file_url',
        scaling: 'fit'
      }
    });
</script>
```

Can any body know why?

Comment: I am able to play files on ubuntu firefox and windows chrome but unable play them on all browser on mac, windows using firefox, chrome using ubuntu.

Comment: I am able to fix this issue by changing flowplayer version in the following line:

    $f("player", "https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf",